# Big commerce (modifying template theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to Big Commerce. I am trying to modify the my CSS for the current theme. I am unable to find the location of the files. I am trying to make modifications to my product titles like removing the text-decorations and changing font-size. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the theme styles using the Bigcommerce theme files editor at *Storefront->My Themes->Current Theme->Advanced->Edit Theme Files*.

Theme scss should be at *assets->scss->theme.scss*.